# Why do these sentences end differently?

Tags: syntax, conjugations, て-form, adjectives

*This clip is taken from the Genki 1 CD (page 145, practice B)*

https://clyp.it/0hidoxpi?token=a6a5bcee7235ba7a1de2723699d145c4

I am confused about why some sentences end differently:

- かったです
- でした
- ありませんでした

When do you end with each one and why?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but this is a pretty basic question that should be covered in detail by your book. Do you really have no clue at all what the differences are? If you do, can you focus the question more specifically on what your problem is? By the way, you have a typo in your last example.

Answer (score 0):

Formal:

あります (present)

〜ます

ありません (negative present)

〜ません

ありました (past)

〜ました

ありませんでした (negative past)

〜ませんでした

Informal:

Ichidan verbs

たべる

〜る

たべない

〜ない

たべた

〜た

たべなかった

〜なかった

Godan verbs

Present:

〜す

〜く/〜ぐ

〜む/〜ぶ/〜ぬ

〜る/〜う/〜つ

Negative:

〜さない

〜かない/〜がない

〜まない/〜ばない/〜なない

〜らない/〜わない/〜たない

Past:

〜した

〜いた/〜いだ

〜んだ/〜んだ/〜んだ

〜った/〜った/〜った

Negative past:

Same as negative, but replace the ない with なかった

話さない

届かない

State of being:

です (present)

じゃない (negative)

でした (past)

じゃなかった (negative past)

い-adjectives

〜い (present)

〜くない (negative)

〜かった (past)

〜くなかった (negative past)

Source: guidetojapanese.org

Comment: 「～かったです」がないようですが。

Answer (score 0):

These three are all polite level speech forms, perhaps referred to as です/ますform. You will come across other levels of politeness later on. I mention this because in other politeness levels the sentence endings change from these.

かったです is the past tense as it applies to i-adjectives (adjectives ending in a い).

e.g.

> すしはおいしかったです
>   The sushi was delicious.

でした is the past tense as it applies to nouns and na-adjectives (adjectives which require な to be added when preceding a noun)

e.g.

> わたしはがくせいでした
>   I was a student

ありませんでした is the negative past tense as it applies to the verb あります (to have or to exist). As a point of reference, the affirmative past tense is ありました.

e.g.

> わたしはくるまがありませんでした
>   I didn't have a car

This ませんでした is the negative past tense for any verb at this politeness level.

> たべます > たべませんでした
>   のみます > のみませんでした